# Make function return unevaluated equation

Tags: hold

I have made this function which outputs the equation of a nth degree polynomial:

```
polynomial[degree_] := (
  result = 0;
  For[count = 1,
        count <= degree,
        result +=
    ToExpression[FromCharacterCode[96 + count]]*x^(degree - count);
        count++;
    ];
  result)
```

This works fine until you set a variable named `a`. Now the `a` in the equation gets replaced by the new value of `a`.

How can I stop this from happening so that `polynomial[1]` always would result in `a` and not the value of `a` even if it is defined.

I would prefer the output of `polynomial` to be an expression and not a string and a would also prefer not to clear the variables.

Example:

```
polynomial[1] (* == a *)

a = 2;
polynomial[1] (* == 2 *)
fixedPolynomial[1] (* == a *)
```

Comment: Do you want to use the polynomials produced for computations or is it just their visual form you are interested in ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction

Questions like this one often suggests that it is not clear how *Mathematica* works and that it always tries to evaluate expressions. Assume the following simple example

```
a = 1;
a + a
a*x + 1
```

In the first line I set `a` to 1 and in the other two I write down an expression. Now I want that in `a+a` the result is 2 like one would expect, but in the `a*x+1` line I want that `a` stays unevaluated.
How should *Mathematica* know that? It always evaluates your expressions if you write it down.

Changing this behavior is not as obvious as it might seem in the first place. It is called *non-standard evaluation* in *Mathematica* and for a novice programmer this might be confusion.
You style of code suggests that you maybe come from an iterative programming language and that you not have used *Mathematica* for long.

First let me point out, that your loop-construct can simply be written as `Sum`

```
Clear[a];
Sum[ToExpression[FromCharacterCode[96 + count]]*x^(5 - count), {count, 5}]

(* e + d x + c x^2 + b x^3 + a x^4 *)
```

I will use this in my code below.

### Solution

My first example showed you, that you can never have an expression like `a+a` which stays that way when `a` has a value, but we can use `HoldForm[a+a]` to make it *look like* that. `HoldForm` is only one of the functions in the `Hold` family.

First lets create your list of parameters. If you replace `ToExpression` with `MakeExpression` every parameter is wrapped in `HoldComplete` which prevents evaluation

```
Table[MakeExpression[FromCharacterCode[96+count]],{count,5}]
(*  
 {HoldComplete[a],HoldComplete[b],HoldComplete[c],
 HoldComplete[d],HoldComplete[e]}
*)
```

Now we create your polynomial using this list of parameters and we simply replace `HoldComplete` with `HoldForm`. This prevents the parameters from evaluation and show them as like they would have no value

```
fixedPolynomial[degree_] := With[
 {parameters = Table[MakeExpression[FromCharacterCode[96 + count]], {count, degree}]},
 Sum[ HoldForm @@ parameters[[count]]*x^(degree - count), {count, 1, degree}]
]
```

Now you always get an unevaluated form

```
a=1;
b=2;
c=3;
poly=fixedPolynomial[5]
(* x^4 a+x^3 b+x^2 c+x d+e *)
```

Although you should always be aware of, that it is only displayed as it would be `a`, `b`, etc. In truth, it is wrapped:

```
InputForm[poly]
(* x^4*HoldForm[a] + x^3*HoldForm[b] + x^2*HoldForm[c] + x*HoldForm[d] + HoldForm[e] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of your function polynomial can be made simpler. But for your question, The problem (as I said in the little comment above) is in evaluation of your `"a"` to the `Symbol a` which is global and has value.

Better to use a method like shown by Bill above and other ways to avoid these sorts of things in first place.

You can see the problem easily:

```
ToExpression@FromCharacterCode[97]
Out[1]= a

a = 1;
ToExpression[FromCharacterCode[97]]
Out[3]= 1
```

But to do what you want, you can use the third option of `ToExpression` using `HoldForm`. But notice that the resulting polynomial will have `HoldForm` in it, so it can't be used as is for computation.

```
ClearAll[polynomial]
polynomial[degree_, x_Symbol] := Module[{count, p, result = 0},

  For[count = 1, count <= degree, count++,

   p = ToExpression[FromCharacterCode[96 + count], InputForm, HoldForm];
   result += p*x^(degree - count)

   ];

  result
  ]
```

now

```
a=1;
polynomial[#, x] & /@ Range[5]
```

gives

[image]

But again, this is just using `HoldForm` in it. Only for display.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative way to define the polynomials:

```
 poly[n_] := Total[Array[a, n] Flatten[x^{Range[n] - 1}]]
```

Instead of using `a`,`b`,`c` as variables, it uses `a[1]`, `a[2]`, etc. This has the advantage that is works for any `n` (the original stops working around 26 or 27 because of the character string).

Answer (score 1):

### Strings

In addition to `HoldForm`, you may wish to know that strings themselves can be used where you need an inert object, and in output they even appear as symbols.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `a` in the output line is still a string, but by default string delimiters are not printed in output.

Because of this you could simply leave out the `ToExpression` part of your code to avoid evaluation you do not want.  Using halirutan's `Sum`:

```
poly1[degree_] := 
  Sum[FromCharacterCode[96 + i]*"x"^(degree - i), {i, degree}]

{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};

poly1[6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Formal Symbols

Formal Symbols exist specifically for cases like this.  They all have the Attribute `Protected` so that they cannot have global values assigned.  Formal Symbols are entered <kbd>Esc</kbd>$x<kbd>Esc</kbd> where `x` is an upper or lower case letter (a-z, A-Z).

This is the method I recommend unless you can't stand the appearance of the dots in the Formal Symbols, in which case you will need to fall back to Strings or `HoldForm`.

```
poly2[degree_] := 
  Sum[ToExpression @ FromCharacterCode[63487 + i] * \[FormalX]^(degree - i), {i, degree}]

poly2[6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]