# Replace symbols with values without evaluation

Tags: evaluation, replacement, hold

If I have assigned values to `a`, `b` and `c`:

```
a=7;
b=5;
c=6;
```

and I select the expression:

```
(a+b)/c
```

and I press `cmd + enter` in the Mathematica frontend, the expression will be replaced by `2`.

I would like to do something similar which would fill in the values of the symbols without evaluating the result. So `(a+b)/c` would be replaced by `(7+5)/6`.

Is there a way of doing this?
If so, can you also assign this to a keyboard shortcut that would replace the selected expression?

**Note:** Assume you don't know the values or the names of the variables. Inputting `(a+b)/c` to a function, should be able to produce something like `(7+5)/6` without having to input `a`, `b` and `c` or `7`, `5` and `6`.

Comment: What should happen when `b = -5`?

Comment: @Kuba either `(7-5)/6` or `(7+(-5))/6`.

Comment: I *swear* this question is a duplicate.  People, please help me find it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've only found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13916/89), only partially duplicate, so I took the liberty to answer.

Comment: @István That's not the one, but thank you for looking first.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - did you mean this [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/make-function-return-unevaluated-equation) ?

Comment: @Ymareth Not that one either, but it's related; I kind of inverse actually. Thanks for looking!

Comment: [Just so you know what's coming](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `OwnValues` and `HoldForm`:

```
{a = 7, b = 5, c = 6};

HoldForm[(a + b)/c] /. OwnValues@a /. OwnValues@b /. OwnValues@c
```

> ```
> (7 + 5)/6
> ```

```
With[{a = a, b = b, c = c}, HoldForm[(a + b)/c]]
```

> ```
> (7 + 5)/6
> ```

Assuming that variables are already defined and you don't want to bother with listing the symbols, and you want to have a function that does it in one go:

```
Attributes[hold] = {HoldAll};
hold[x_] := HoldForm@x /. Cases[Hold@x, s_Symbol :> (HoldPattern@s -> s), Infinity];

hold[(a + b)/c]
```

> ```
> (7 + 5)/6
> ```

Comment: Given that I don't want to type the names of the symbols again, is there a way of just inputting `(a+b)/c` and the function would figure out to do `/. OwnValues@symbol` for each symbol?

Comment: I know this a probably even harder, but would it be possible to output `(7+5)/(-6)` instead of `-(1/6)*(7+5)` when `c=-6`?

Comment: `a = b = c = 1; hold[(a + b)/c]`

Comment: @Tyilo If you examine `FullForm[(a + b)/c]` (without values for `a, b, c`), you will realize that it is already represented as `Times[Plus[a, b], Power[c, -1]]`. So that is again an entirely different question.

Answer (score 5):

```
Hold[(a + b)/c] /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4} /. Hold -> Defer

(*   (1 + 3)/4   *)

Hold[(a + b)/c] /. {a -> 1, b -> -3, c -> 4} /. Hold -> Defer

(*   (1 - 3)/4   *)

    Hold[(a + b)/c] /. {a -> 1, b -> -3, c -> -4} /. Hold -> Defer

(*   -(1/4) (1 - 3)   *)
```

Comment: Just a note: `Defer @@ Hold[(a + b)/c] ...` etc. works as well.

Comment: Given that I don't want to type the names of the symbols and the values again, is there a way of just inputting `(a+b)/c` and the function would figure out the values itself?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work when the variables has already been defined.

Comment: `Defer` instead of `Hold` without replacement should work. It already holds

Comment: @Rojo That was my first idea also, but it did not work. This (a + b)/c // Defer /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4} returns (a + b)/c;  this (a + b)/c /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4} // Defer and this Defer[(a + b)/c /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4}] return (a + b)/c /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4}

Comment: @Tyilo from your explanations I do not really understand, what do you have in mind. If you really need a further assistance you should probably give some further explanations along with your own attempts. Then I (and the others) will probably better understand, what are you after.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch `(a + b)/c // Defer /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4}` is the same as `(Defer /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4})[(a + b)/c]`, which is not what you want. In the last ones you are holding all. You need `Defer[(a + b)/c] /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4}`

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: answer rewrite*

This question in its base form is a duplicate, but since I cannot find the original, and since you extended the question to something more unique than what I recall, I shall provide a short answer.

You asked:

> I know this a probably even harder, but would it be possible to output `(7+5)/(-6)` instead of `-(1/6)*(7+5)` when `c=-6`?

For that kind of control see for example: [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882)

Combining that with `RuleCondition`, described in [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replace-inside-held-expression/29319#29319), we can use:

```
SetAttributes[{defer, fill}, HoldAll]

MakeBoxes[defer[args__], fmt_] := Block[{Times}, MakeBoxes[Defer[args], fmt]]

fill[expr_] := defer[expr] /. x_Symbol :> RuleCondition[x]
```

Now:

```
{a, b, c} = {7, 5, -6};

fill[(a + b)/c]
```

> ```
> (7+5)*-(1/6)
> ```

Because this uses [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) you can use the output of `fill` as input and it will fully evaluate.

Comment: I just realized that I read the comment I quoted completely backward.  Time for a break I guess!  I'll fix this later.

Answer (score 0):

In the same search that found your post, I also found: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100152/76328

I tailored Edmund's approach just slightly to fit my needs.  I hadn't heard of Inactivate before, but it performs substitutions while not evaluating the main expression.  It sounds like a simple solution to this post?

That said, I do like István Zachar's general-case approach as well.

Tailored version noted above:

```
InactiveAndActive = Function[expr, Column@Through@{Inactivate, Identity}@Unevaluated@expr, HoldAll];
```

EDIT: I just noticed that the above doesn't format things like 1/x in StandardForm.  A better solution is:

```
HoldAndEvaluate = Function[expr, Column@Through@{Inactivate, Identity}@Unevaluated@expr /. Inactive[x_] -> HoldForm@*x, HoldAll];
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica has the function Hold which prevents evaluation, until you Release that Hold.

```
Hold[(a+b)/c] /.{a->1,b->2,c->3}
```

gives

```
Hold[(1 + 2)/3]
```

Then

```
Release[Hold[(1 + 2)/3]]
```

will give

```
1
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as Alexei's answer. I wouldn't consider it a different one.

Comment: I posted it on an un-refreshed page, didn't see Alexi's answer until afterwards.  Gotta be quick round here clearly.

Comment: Not really. I tried to get rid of Hold in the output. The advantage of the present approach is the ease of its later evaluation it, if needed, as it is shown above. Its penalty is to have Hold visible, which (it seems) was not desired by Tyilo. The penalty of my approach is that the way to evaluate the result is less straightforward. It may be done however by /.Defer->Evaluate.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch If you're referring to the downvote, that wasn't me.

Comment: @Tyilo No, the up- and downvotes are no matter for me. I just discuss the essence as I understand it. Have fun.