# Is it possible to construct a fullform trace function

Tags: evaluation

Is it possible to construct a `FullFormTrace` function that takes an arbitrary expression and prints a sequence  (or returns a list) of the evaluation steps in full form. For instance

```
FullFormTrace[(1+2*3)^2]
```

would output

```
Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],2] 
Power[Plus[1,6],2] 
Power[7,2] 
49
```

The same output would come if the expression is entered in full form to begin with so

```
FullFormTrace[Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],Plus[1,1]]]
```

would give the same output

I tried the `Trace` function

```
Trace[Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],2]]
```

but I get as output

```
{{{2 3,6},1+6,7},7^2,49}
```

which is not of the above form.

Comment: Related:[19542](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100100/19542)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use `Inactivate` to step through the calculation while evaluating in place.  Then convert these results into `FullForm` with `HoldForm` to prevent evaluation.

First a helper function to evaluate in place.

```
ClearAll[traceInPlace];
SetAttributes[traceInPlace, {HoldFirst}];
traceInPlace[expr_] :=
 With[{ex = Inactivate[expr]},
  FoldList[
   MapAt[Replace[Inactive -> Identity], #2]@#1 &,
   ex,
   Reverse@Position[ex, Inactive]
   ]]
```

`traceInPlace` works like so

```
traceInPlace[(1 + 2*3)^2] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then it is only a matter of converting these to `FullForm` and removing the `Inactive` heads created by `Inactivate`.

```
Activate@HoldForm@FullForm@# & /@ traceInPlace[(1 + 2*3)^2] // Column
```

> ```
> Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],2]
> Power[Plus[1,6],2]
> Power[7,2]
> 49
> ```

Each item is wrapped in `Hold` but if it were not then it would evaluate.

You can also use different forms. For example:

```
Activate@HoldForm@TraditionalForm@# & /@ traceInPlace[(1 + 2*3)^2] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

**Update**: Thanks to @jjc385 for suggesting `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`. Change made above.

Comment: You can replace `Hold` with `HoldForm` to have the same results without a wrapper being printed.  +1

Comment: @jjc385 Nice addition. Will update. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer. One suggestion: Slightly simpler is ``ReplacePart[#1, #2->Identity]&`` instead of ``MapAt[Replace[Inactive->Identity], #2]@#1&``

Comment: @CarlWoll That is a good suggestion.  Completely forgot about ReplacePart.  Thanks.

Comment: If I enter `Activate@HoldForm@FullForm@# & /@ traceInPlace[(h + 2*3)^2] // Column` I get multiple copes of `Power[Plus[6, h], 2]`. It would be nice if superfluous copies are removed from the output.

Comment: @BobUeland It is not a superfluous copy.  Second line shows the `2 x 3` result; 6. The third line shows the `h + 6` result; which happens to be `h + 6`. Then the forth line shows the `(h + 6)^2` result; which happens to be  `(h + 6)^2`. Try `Activate@HoldForm@FullForm@# & /@ (traceInPlace[(h + 2*3)^2] /. 
    h -> 2) // Column` to see.

Answer (score 6):

```
ff = FullForm /@ Trace[Power[Plus[1, Times[2, 3]], 2], TraceOriginal -> True];

sf = ToString /@ ff;

Fold[StringDelete[#1, #2] &, sf, {"HoldForm[", "]," ~~ EndOfString}]
```

> ```
> {Power[Plus[1, Times[2, 3]], 2]],
>  List[Power]], List[Plus[1, Times[2, 3]]], List[Plus]],
>    List[1]], List[Times[2, 3]], List[Times]], List[2]], List[3]],
>    Times[2, 3]], 6]], Plus[1, 6]], 7]], List[2]], Power[7, 2]], 49]}
> ```

Still a lot of junk in there, and no clear way to parse it to get the OP's requirement ...

> ```
> Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],2] 
> Power[Plus[1,6],2] 
> Power[7,2] 
> 49
> ```

Comment: Thanks although I will have to tweak it into right form, but the main idea is there!

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way.

Find the depth of the expression and evaluate parts level by level.

```
ex = Hold[(1 + 2*3)^2];
f[expr_] := 
 Replace[FullForm[expr], x_ :> With[{eval = x}, eval /; True], {#}] & /@ 
  Range[Depth[expr], 2, -1]

f[ex] // Column
```

> ```
> Hold[Power[Plus[1,Times[2,3]],2]]
> Hold[Power[Plus[1,6],2]]
> Hold[Power[7,2]]
> Hold[49]
> ```

For more information on the evaluation, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136604/evaluate-beyond-one-level-within-hold-in-mathematica) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression).

Comment: Is it possible to make this evaluate each operation in turn instead of evaluating all operations on a particular level at the same time? e.g.  `f[Hold[(1 + 2*3)^2 + (1 + 2*3)^2]]` (+1)

Answer (score 4):

The following shows the output of `Trace` in `FullForm`, which is not exactly the desired output shown in the OP.  But then the output shown does not correspond to the description of the problem exactly, so my guess is that this is what is desired.

```
Trace[(1 + 2*3)^2] /. HoldForm[e_] :> HoldForm[FullForm@e]
```

[image]

Possible alternatives, depending on how much of the evaluation sequence is desired:

```
TraceScan[Print[# /. HoldForm[e_] :> HoldForm[FullForm[e]]] &, (1 + 2*3)^2]

TraceScan[
 If[MatchQ[#, HoldForm[e_] /; ! AtomQ[Unevaluated@e]], 
   Print[# /. HoldForm[e_] :> HoldForm[FullForm[e]]]] &, (1 + 2*3)^2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm late I know, but I tried a different approach that is related to what Micheal did. I used `Trace` in the following form

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The structure of each list in the output is similar. Either it consists of only one element when the sub-expression is atomic or it consists of

- original sub-expression
- evaluation of head
- evaluation of all arguments
- expression with evaluated arguments
- final result

If you look at the inner `2^2` list, you see that it always follows this and indeed, this is roughly how the main evaluation works. My goal was to take only the output of trace and construct a sequence of lines, where each line shows the *whole* current expression and highlights which part is currently evaluated by Mathematica. This makes very clear, how sub-expressions are transformed and how the final result is achieved. It will work like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To do the highlighting work, I didn't use expressions. Instead, I create an expression tree. This spares me the work of continually preventing expressions from evaluation, and I can quickly highlight specific subtrees.

```
SetAttributes[tree, {HoldAllComplete}];
tree[(h_)[args___]] := node[tree[h], Sequence @@ (tree /@ Unevaluated[{args}])];
tree[e_?AtomQ] := leaf[e]

tree[1 + 3^2] // TreeForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next step was to code a pretty-printer for such trees. This is basically walking the tree and creating low-level boxes for the nodes.

```
TreePrint[t_] := Print[DisplayForm[StyleBox[treePrint[t], FontFamily -> "Courier"]]];
bold[s_] := StyleBox[s, FontWeight -> Bold];
color[s_] := StyleBox[s, FontColor -> ColorData[3, 10]];
treePrint[hilit[arg_]] := color[treePrint[arg]];
treePrint[node[head_, childs___]] := RowBox[{treePrint[head], bold["["], 
    RowBox[Riffle[treePrint /@ {childs}, ", "]], bold["]"]}];
treePrint[leaf[l_]] := ToString[l];
```

Now I can get the *full form* very easily

```
tree[1 + 3^2] // TreePrint

(* Plus[1, Power[3, 2]] *)
```

If I like to highlight a subtree, I just have to wrap the node in `hilit` and the whole sub-tree is printed in red.

The algorithm for transforming a trace output is not really hard. I just need to go through the list and replace parts of the current tree. For instance, in my very first example: If I ignore the evaluation of the head and arguments for the moment, it is basically

- set the current tree to 1+2^2
- set the current tree to 1+4
- set the current tree to 5

As soon as you accept, that evaluating the arguments is the same thing, only on a sub-tree of the whole expression, it's easy to understand. To know on which sub-tree I'm working, I need to carefully store how often I dived into an argument list and at which position I am.

```
Module[{$currentTree = Null},
 SetAttributes[SimpleTrace, {HoldFirst}];
 SimpleTrace[expr_] := scan[Trace[expr, TraceOriginal -> True]];

 scan[elms_List, pos___] := Module[{count = 1},
   Do[
     Switch[e,
       _HoldForm,
       $currentTree[[pos]] = hilit@Apply[tree, e];
       TreePrint[$currentTree];
       $currentTree[[pos]] = $currentTree[[pos, 1]],
       _List,
       scan[e, pos, count++]
       ];
     , {e, elms}
     ];
   ]
 ]
```

After the `_HoldForm` in the switch, I'm temporarily adding `hilit` to the current sub-tree, print it and remove the `hilit` again. This all can be implemented properly, but it's only a showcase after all. Now, you are good to go to study the original question:

```
SimpleTrace[(1 + 2*3)^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally, it takes only some minor changes to check if the tree had changed and print the tree only if there was a structural replacement. This gives the output that was originally asked for:

```
SimpleTrace[(1 + 2*3)^2]

(*
Power[Plus[1, Times[2, 3]], 2]
Power[Plus[1, 6], 2]
Power[7, 2]    
49
*)
```

### Restrictions

This approach only works, when trace follows the described pattern consistently. This is not always true when functions like `Map` or `Fold` are used that don't transform the current tree, but evaluate independent sub-expressions. One simple example is

```
Trace[FoldList[#1 + #2 &, 0, {10, 11}], TraceOriginal -> True] // Column

FoldList[#1+#2&,0,{10,11}]
{FoldList}
{#1+#2&,{Function},#1+#2&}
{0}
{{10,11}}
(* next is the final new sub tree *)
FoldList[#1+#2&,0,{10,11}]
(* here a new sub-evaluation is evaluated 
   that cannot be included into the last sub-tree *)
{(#1+#2&)[0,10],{#1+#2&},{0},{10},(#1+#2&)[0,10],0+10,{Plus},{0},{10},0+10,10}
{(#1+#2&)[10,11],{#1+#2&},{10},{11},(#1+#2&)[10,11],10+11,{Plus},{10},{11},10+11,21}
{0,10,21}
```